# What is mathematical equation of the Gravitational force between three objects?

Tags: mathematical-physics

This is mathematical equation of the Gravitational force between two objects:
$$F_G=\frac{GM_1M_2}{r^2}$$

what is mathematical equation of the Gravitational force between three objects?

Answer (score 3):

The gravitational force due to two objects, $M_1, M_2$ on another object, $M_3$, is the **vector sum** of the forces due to $M_1$ and $M_2$ individually on $M_3$, i.e. $$\vec{F}_{\text{net}} = \vec{F}_{1,3} + \vec{F}_{2,3}$$
where $|\vec F_{1,3}| = \frac{GM_1M_3}{r_{1,3}^2}$, and $|\vec F_{2,3}| = \frac{GM_2M_3}{r_{2,3}^2}$.

This is generally not (I repeat : **NOT**) the same as the sum of the magnitude of the forces, which is otherwise given by:
$$\frac{GM_1M_3}{r_{1,3}^2} + \frac{GM_2M_3}{r_{2,3}^2}$$

A simple illustration is to put three equal masses on the vertices of an equilateral triangle, whose base is parallel to the ground: You will find that the net gravitational force on the top-most mass due to the other two masses is upwards.

If you want a more explicit formula, you will need information of the direction of the individual forces

Comment: For a complete answer, I suggest you also write the formulas for the size of $F_{1,3}$ and $F_{2,3}$.

Comment: @5xum Updated, thanks!

Comment: The formula with directions is not that much more complicated, $$\vec F_{2,3} = -\frac{GM_2M_3}{r_{2,3}^3}\vec r_{2,3}=-\nabla_{r_3}\left(\frac{GM_2M_3}{r_{2,3}}\right),$$ where $\vec r_{2,3}=\vec r_{3}-\vec r_{2}$.